# Angular 12 to Angular 13 upgrade - define what to change in package.json?

Tags: javascript, angular, upgrade, package.json, angular13

I have an Angular 12 project and package.json. To upgrade to Angular 13,
this manual https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0  states to execute

```
ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 
ng update @angular/material@13
```

So, for package.json I need to modify package.json instead. Manually. **Correct?** How to know what changes need to be done in package.json based on the info above?  `@angular/core`,  `@angular/material`,  `@angular/material?` Any other dependencies? I guess **Yes**.

Should I prefer to upgrade `@angular/core` to `13.0.3` or `13.3.11` **or** the very last `13.Y.Z`?
How to guess, versions in **what** dependencies and to what version need to be upgraded?
Should it be upgraded **manually** and then run `npm i`?

Comment: Why do you need to do it manually?

Comment: Ok, if not manually, then will ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13  modify my package.json?

Comment: If you have version control you shouldn't be afraid of running these to find out and if you have any issues doing `git reset --hard` and `git clean -fd` to undo. If you have uncommited local changes you can stash them before and then stash pop them after. But the answer is yes.

Comment: I ran it but I don't see any changes in package.json   ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13 --allow-di
rty --force
Repository is not clean. Update changes will be mixed with pre-existing changes.
Using package manager: 'npm'
Collecting installed dependencies...
Found 83 dependencies.
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
Package '@angular/core' is already up to date.
Package '@angular/cli' is already up to date.
====
No changes in package.json

Comment: To apply changes by executing ng update I had to run it with a flag --force. That helped.